# Using Banach lemma to prove some matrix norm inequality

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $A+E$ be two non-singular matrices. Also let $\|X\|=\sqrt{\rho(XX^T)}$. Using Banach lemma prove that

$$\|(A+E)^{-1}-A^{-1}\|\leq\|E\|\|A^{-1}\|\|(A+E)^{-1}\|$$

[image: Banach Lemma:]

Comment: Banach has proven many lemmas. Which one do you want us to use?

Comment: I don't know. Any one that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that by simple algebraic manipulations
$$
(A+E)^{-1}-A^{-1} = (A+E)^{-1}AA^{-1}-(A+E)^{-1}(A+E)A^{-1}=-(A+E)^{-1}EA^{-1}.
$$
No Banach Lemma needed.